# Trying to connect to XMPP server with aSmack on Android gets me "no dns resolver active"

Tags: android, dns, xmpp, smack

I made this as simple as I can in code. I am using asmack library for android in version 8-0.8.3.

My code:

```
package info.zajacmp3.servercommunication;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class XmppService extends Service{



    public void xmppService() throws XMPPException {

        Connection conn1 = new XMPPConnection("jabber.org");
        conn1.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        //TODO:actions to perform when service is created
        try {
            xmppService();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Replace with service binding
        return null;
    }
}
```

It freeze my app and cause me and error: no dns resolver active. There is nothing on the web about it.

I do really hope to get some help or clues.

Also tried like this:

private final static String server_host = "jabber.org";
private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;

public void xmppService() throws XMPPException {

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration( server_host, SERVER_PORT);
XMPPConnection m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        try {
             SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
             config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);     
             m_connection.connect();
            Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

@UPDATE:

Using smack library instead of asmack gets me the same problem.
I get no error log, but after disconnecting debugger I get:

[image]

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Smack instead of aSmack. Asmack is a patched and enhanced version of Smack and aSmack is somewhat dead. In Smack code refactoring is done, added some new methods and refactored DNS classes.

See this [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)

**UPDATE**
After seeing your error log it seems to be the problem of **network call on main UI thread**

***How to resolve NetworkOnMainThread exception?***
Use AsyncTask which makes your network call on different thread(in background) rather than on app's main thread.

Move your code to AsynTask:-

```
private class ConnectToXmpp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration( server_host, SERVER_PORT);
          XMPPConnection m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    try {
         SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
         config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);     
         m_connection.connect();
        Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

}
```

And now you can execute your AsyncTask:-

```
new ConnectToXmpp().execute();
```

With this your network call will be made in background in different thread.

See this **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

Comment: Thank you very very much for your interest in this matter @amrinder007 . I tried and went back to smack in newest version. I get the same error. I updated the topic with this error

Comment: What makes you think that [aSmack](http://asmack.org) is dead? There was a recent release only a few weeks ago. And smack won't work on Android without modifications, that is why aSmack exists. You can read more about aSmack here: http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/226881#226881

Comment: Asmack is not dead , but its beaning maintained by @Flow himself.

Answer (score 6):

If aSmack tells you that no DNS resolver is active then you most likely did not initialize the static code of aSmack as [aSmack's README](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/README.asmack) told you to do.

From the README

> In order to work correctly on Android, you need to register Smack's
>   XMPP Providers and Extensions manually and init some static code
>   blocks before you doing any XMPP activty. Calling
>   SmackAndroid.init(Context) (in org.jivesoftware.smack) will do this
>   for you.

Simply call `SmackAndroid.init(Context)` and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
            int portInt = 5222;
            String host = "192.168.0.104";
            String service = "something.local" //Domain name
            String username = "username" //Without domain name
            String password = "password"

            // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, portInt,service);
            connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            //connConfig.setCompressionEnabled(true);
            connConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                connConfig.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
                connConfig.setTruststorePassword(null);
                connConfig.setTruststorePath(null);
                Log.i("XMPP", "Build Icecream");

            } else {
                connConfig.setTruststoreType("BKS");
                String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
                if (path == null)
                    path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                            + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                            + "cacerts.bks";
                connConfig.setTruststorePath(path);
                Log.i("XMPP", "Build less than Icecream ");

            }
            connConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
            XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPP", "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
                // publishProgress("Connected to host " + HOST);
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPP", "Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPP", ex.toString());
                //publishProgress("Failed to connect to " + HOST);
                //xmppClient.setConnection(null);
            }

            try {
                connection.login(username, password);
                Log.i("androxmpp", "Logged in " + connection.getUser() + ". Authenticated : "+connection.isAuthenticated());
            } catch(Exception ex){

                Log.i("androxmpp", "Login Unsuccessfull ");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```